# Manipulating request.FILES in django POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a file upload view in django. I have a model form. In POST method *request.FILES* contains all the files.

I want to do some extra work on the uploaded files in request.FILES. I saved the files locally and do some extra work. But I can not assign the files in request.FILES.

I made a dictionary like -

```
data_dict = {
                        'a_file': open(tmp_dir + "/a_repro.a", 'r'),
                        'b_file': open(tmp_dir + "/b_repro.b", 'r'),

                        'c_file': open(tmp_dir + "/c_repro.c", 'r'),

                        'd_file': open(tmp_dir + "/d_repro.d", 'r'),

                    }
```

But I can not assign like -

```
form = MyUploadForm(request.POST, data_dict)
```

or,

> `request.FILES = data_dict`

But it does not work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to manioulate the `request.FILES`. Because, form will take the parameters `data`, `files`.
For your requirement you can do as follows

```
files = {
   'a_file': open(tmp_dir + "/a_repro.a", 'r').read(),
}

form = MyUploadForm(data=request.POST, files=files)
```

for reference see: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L74